# What to leave off/include in my resume

Tags: resume

I have worked in the finance industry the last 5 years. The previous 8 years of employment were all random warehouse/retail jobs and if I list all of them they would take up at least half a page. Is there a summarised format I could put in my resume or should I leave it off and explain in a cover letter? Open to all suggestions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a hiring manager reading a resume, I'm mostly interested in your experience. It's important that you have recent and relevant experience, and it's also good to know that you have a long and continuous(ish) employment record. *Where* you worked, especially in older jobs, is less important - that might come up for a background check, but it is not something that will help for resume screening.

Assuming you are continuing with a career in the finance industry, you could lump all your warehouse/retail experience into one short paragraph, at "various employers" for the 8 years. List the most useful and relevant points for your experience over the whole 8 years.

Comment: *"it's also good to know that you have a long and continuous(ish) employment record"*. What kind of assumptions do HMs make about people without what they'd consider a "continuous(ish) employment record"?

Comment: @ray Depends on how the gaps are filled, and on the culture.

Comment: I like this answer and agree. I would add to it in order to answer the specific question *"Is there a summarised format I could put in my resume"* I think the answer is yes - list "Warehouse/retail positions" with a sentence describing the work and a bullet list of employers with date ranges for each. You're covering what HorusKol mentioned (showing continuity) without wasting space going into detail.